# Sequelize joined table column names for BelongsToMany association

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for my postgres database and I have the following two tables:

1. Artist
2. Album

They are previously defined using `sequelize.define`

It is an M:N relationship, so I decided to go with the following associations:

`Artist.belongsToMany(Albums, { through: 'ArtistAlbums' }`

`Album.belongsToMany(Artist, { through: 'ArtistAlbums' }`

This works well, however the table ArtistAlbums later on has very weird column names:

"ArtistArtistId", "AlbumAlbumId" referring to the primary keys of Artist (artistId) and Album (albumId).
However I'd like to only have "albumId" and "artistId" in there, but can't figure out how to tell sequelize to do just that. I tried the following:

1. Tried to specify a model in the through option which specifies two keys like that.

Issue: I'd have my keys as well as the generated keys in the table

2. I tried adding the `unique: false` option to it, which also did not work.
3. I tried using "as" and "sourceKey", "targetKey" as well as "uniqueKey", which all did not help.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT 1:

I think using otherKey I was able to set one of the columns to the name I want it to be, but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
Artist.belongsToMany(Album, {
  through: 'ArtistAlbums',
  unique: false,
  foreignKey: 'artistId'
});

Album.belongsToMany(Artist, {
  through: 'ArtistAlbums',
  unique: false,
  foreignKey: 'albumId'
});
```

Note that the **only difference** between my code and yours is the `foreignKey` definition.

The code above created the following result in my postgreSQL DB. (I omitted some data):

```sql
CREATE TABLE public."ArtistAlbums"
(
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "artistId" integer NOT NULL,
  "albumId" integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "ArtistAlbums_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("artistId", "albumId"),
  CONSTRAINT "ArtistAlbums_albumId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("albumId")
      REFERENCES public."Album" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT "ArtistAlbums_artistId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("artistId")
      REFERENCES public."Artist" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

To produce the other tables I used:

```js
const Artist = sequelize.define(
  'Artist',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true
  }
);

const Album = sequelize.define(
  'Album',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! That worked. With the exception that I had to modify the structure a bit, given that in your answer through, unique & foreignKey are on the same level. I am using typescript and the parameters are `through: { model: 'ArtistsAlbum', unique: false }, foreignKey: 'artistId'`